# Collision with zRotation

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, collision

So I want to fire a beam of laser from the enemy to the player.

[image: Laser beam from enemy in the sky down a player]

so the laser sweeps from left to right. So i use the zrotation as seen below

[image: Enemy in the sky with a laser beam changing angle towards the player]

As you can see, the frame of the player is intersecting the laserbeam. How do i overcome this problem such that i can detect the collision of laser image and the player image?

Comment: Just to make things clearer, basically its giving me a false positive collision; because the frames are overlapping. How do i over come this problem?